# Java, Android - Как запустить другое приложение внутри активити

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток! 
Существует ли возможность запускать другое приложение из текущего активити? То есть, чтобы при выборе необходимого приложения, было активити с выбранным приложением.

Comment: @Defenses, например? не совсем понятна суть

Comment: Тоже послушаю ответы

Comment: @zayn1991 , находясь в открытом приложении, к примеру по клику на элемент списка (список будет состоять из приложений установленных на андроид) открыть некоторое окно (активити) другого приложения.

Comment: @Defenses ну, раз кастомные оболочки есть, такие, как nova launcher, значит такое возможно. Никогда не делал, так что пример не смогу написать